# Fetch API: how to determine if an error is a network error

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

So I have some code like this:

```js
async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(/* ... */);
  const json = await response.json();
  return transform(json);
}
```

Where `transform` can throw some of its own errors.

---

I'm try to catch for network errors from the `fetch` API.

```js
try {
  const data = await getData();

  // ...
  return // ...
} catch (e) {
  if (isNetworkError(e)) {
    return localStorage.getItem('...');
  }

  throw e;
}
```

**My question is how do I implement `isNetworkError` that works across browsers?** Note: that this should only return true if the network is offline.

It seems like both chrome and firefox throws a `TypeError` but the messages they have are different on each.

- Firefox: `TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."`
- Chrome: `TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Comment: You saved me!  THank you!  Your approach is perfect to check if application has internet or not withtout crashing entire app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the first promise rejects, it's a network error. That's the only time it does.

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status
> even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve
> normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on
> network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

From Mozilla developer page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

---

Edit: As pointed out in the comments and other answers, you should also pay attention to the line "or if anything prevented the request from completing". Which means that the initial Promise of `fetch` will reject on network errors in addition to other problems. Like for example, an invalid URL or a CORS error.

If fetch is able to successfully reach the server with your request, it will resolve the first Promise successfully, otherwise the first promise will reject. In the case of CORS, the error occurs before your request is actually sent out (in the OPTIONS request), which is why the error occurs in the first Promise.

Comment: CORS error is not a network error. And that's when this assumption fails.

Comment: Invalid protocol. Invalid header. URL includes credentials... are also non-network errors where `fetch` rejects.

Answer (score 7):

As a client of `fetch`, you can't differentiate network errors from other errors caused by building an incorrect request, as both are thrown as `TypeError`s. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#exceptions).

This is quite a flaw, as application defects that cause an incorrectly built request may go unnoticed, masked as if they were circumstantial network errors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a perfect answer for you. The easiest to solve your exact problem is to implement `isNetworkError` as a type guard. Maybe there are common properties on the firefox/chrome error object that allows you to detect specifically these.

The alternative is to catch errors closer to where you do `fetch()` and rethrow the error as something you can easily detect.

```
async function getData() {
  let response;

  try {
    response = await fetch(/* ... */);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new MyCustomNetworkError(err.message);
  }
  const json = await response.json();
  return transform(json);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a [package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-network-error) that makes it easy to check whether an error is a network error:

```js
import isNetworkError from 'is-network-error';

async function getUnicorns() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('unicorns.json');
        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        if (isNetworkError(error)) {
            return localStorage.getItem('…');
        }

        throw error;
    }
}

console.log(await getUnicorns());
```

If you don't want to depend on a package for this, feel free to copy-paste the [contents](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-network-error/blob/main/index.js) into your project.